# Help me identify

Tags: identify-this-bike

Saw this roadie (possibly 00's) in the back of my uncle's warehouse, can someone identify this bike for me?[image: identify]

Answer (score 4):

Its a blue 80's road bike.   And its missing some parts, like brake calipers, saddle, chain and probably other things.

One distinctive earlier 80s feature is teh lack of under-bottom-bracket cable routing.  Instead there's a "flair pipe" which is clamped around the lower downtube and the inner cables pass over the bottom bracket.  That's even possibly a 70's vintage feature.

Knowing the exact brand won't really help unless you're looking for a full rebuild back to original spec.  Instead, almost every older bike uses a small range of standard parts and fitments.  There is little practical use knowing if this is a Raleigh or a Vincere - its clearly a heavy steel frame road bike.

If you can add a clear photo of a head tube badge or some other markings, then we might have more of a chance.